# DNN ListX module configuration

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-settings

All I could get about DNN ListX control is the following link

http://dnnuke.blogspot.in/2007/09/using-listx-component-to-create.html

The link provides information about the configuration but where can I see all those screens to edit the query and contentPane items?

Any more information about ListX is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research on ListX I found that Bi4ce ListsX was replaced by OWS (Open Web Studio).

I installed OWS on my website and upgraded my ListX to OWS. After upgrading I could easily locate the settings and perform all types of configuration I needed.

[Here](http://www.openwebstudio.com/Community/Forums/tabid/55/forumid/1/threadid/22441/scope/posts/Default.aspx) are many useful resources to learn about OWS.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are having trouble locating information because ListX is an old and unsupported module. You probably should look for an alternative.  Two choices include 2sxc and Open Content.  Both are free and open source.